# Unable to mount exfat drive on macos

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I have a MacBook and 2TB hard drive with the format exFAT. I formatted on Linux and tries plugging it on my MacBook and I am unable to mount it. Please help

Comment: What happens when you try? What does it look like in Disk Utility? Does it show up in Terminal using `diskutil list`? ExFAT should be natively read/writable in macOS.

Comment: When I plug it in it shows the drive in disk utility but it is not mounted. When I click on the mount button nothings happens. After a minute of waiting it gives an error.